# Max file upload limit php

Tags: php

I want to avoid the following error

> Warning: POST Content-Length of 13610816 bytes exceeds the limit of 10485760 bytes in Unknown on line 0

I have already set upload_max_filesize, post_max_size, and memory_limit in my php.ini file and I got the code below from stackoverflow though it seems not to work. Please help

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' 
&& empty($_POST)
&& empty($_FILES)
&& $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'] > 0){

$displayMaxSize = ini_get('post_max_size');

switch(substr($displayMaxSize,-1)) {

case 'G':
  $displayMaxSize = $displayMaxSize * 1024;
case 'M':
  $displayMaxSize = $displayMaxSize * 1024;
case 'K':
   $displayMaxSize = $displayMaxSize * 1024;
}

$error = 'Posted data is too large. '.
       $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'].
       ' bytes exceeds the maximum size of '.
       $displayMaxSize.' bytes.';
}
```

Comment: this doesn't make any sense `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' 
&& empty($_POST)
&& empty($_FILES)
&& $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'] > 0){` especially the last one. And where's the form that goes with this?

Comment: plus, if running local and made changes to system files, make sure you restarted everything

Comment: can you post your php.ini values of upload_max_filesize, post_max_size, and memory_limit ? it seams your upload content is approx 13 mb and your limit set to 10 mb

Comment: upload_max_filesize=10M, post_max_size=10M

Answer (score 2):

find this by file upload

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; File Uploads ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Whether to allow HTTP file uploads.
; http://php.net/file-uploads
file_uploads = On
```

find this by upload_max

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 128M

; Maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a single request
max_file_uploads = 20
```

Answer (score -1):

Put this code top of your page and change the desired value

ini_set('post_max_size', '100M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '100M');